# when is a contractible subset of a contractible space a retract?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In my topology course, we have just proved that a retract of a contractible space is contractible, but I am curious about the converse.

If X is a contractible subset of Eulclidean space and A is contractible and A $\subset$ X, what must also be true about A to make it a retract of X?

Comment: A retract of such (say) a convex subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is an AR (absolute retract), and there are very tchnical characterisations of AR's in general (due to Borsuk, IIRC, see Hu's book on AR's). So I think you won't find any nice and easy characterisations of such $A$.

Comment: An example to show that some assumptions are necessary: the comb space $C$ is contractible, but the inclusion $C^2\hookrightarrow I^2$ admits no retraction.